# Facebook iOS SDK: Custom Facebook Like button delegates touch to FB Like Button Social Plugin

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

Here is my task: User should be able to like the Facebook Page by clicking on custom Facebook Button without redirecting to Facebook from my iOS app.

I've found the [article](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes) in which is stated:

> The og.likes action can refer to any open graph object or URL, except for Facebook Pages or Photos.

Since I can't use FB OpenGraph API for liking, my idea is to implement FB's social plugin Like Button, hide it somewhere and somehow delegate touches to it that are received on my custom like button, but I'm not sure if that is allowed by Facebook..? If not, is there some other way of liking Facebook Page without redirecting from my app?